# Generate a random sequence of chars and concatenate with itself into a list.

Tags: c#, string, random

Hy

I have the following method to produce n random number of chars

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            String lista = new string(chars.Select(c => chars[random.Next(chars.Length)]).Take(int.Parse(textNo.Text)).ToArray());

            var result = String.Join(",", lista.ToCharArray(0, lista.Length));
                var concatenare = result.Concat(result);

            textLast.Text = concatenare;

        }
```

I want to produce in var concatenare a list of chars concatenated with itself.

For example if my program will produce 4 random chars "a, d, e, f," concatenare will contain " a,a,d,d,e,e,f,f"

Sincerly,

Comment: Are duplicates allowed? Like `nmvaudfja..` which has two  `a`?

Comment: from your description, it seems like you're asking how to create a string consisting of some randomly selected characters. You have your string lista. Isn't that what you're trying to do?

Comment: in other words, I do not know what your var result and var contatenare are adding to your solution, because it seems like the goal is to create something like list

Comment: There are two steps. Generate a random sequence, and then double each char occurrence. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var concatenare = string.Join(",", lista.SelectMany(c => new []{c, c}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         string concat="";
       var chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwuvxyz0123456789";
          var rand=new Random();
          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
          {
              char ch = chars[rand.Next(0, chars.Length)];
            concat += "," + ch + "," + ch;
          }
```